# 1uncaught reference error: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why do I get this error on 2 of my externally called JavaScript files?

I tried the code inside my index.html file and it ran perfectly.

I've called all my scripts before stylesheets.

There are 4 scripts running on this page, all JavaScript, 2 of them work but 2 of them don't.

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery first?

Comment: What is the code that uses `$`? It depends on the context what it is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting jQuery script tag on top of the other script tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for this, I never thought about calling the jQuery library script before other scripts.

Comment: Thanx for answering this question and not considering it as "downvotable", it helps

Answer (score 3):

You will receive this error if you are trying to use jQuery without having included the library.

Did you forget to include the jQuery library? Or maybe your url to the .js file is incorrect.